# Mercurial Subrepositories: Prevent accidental recursive commits and pushes

Tags: version-control, mercurial, dvcs, mercurial-subrepos

I work on a team where we have a code in a mercurial repository with several subrepositories:

```
main/
main/subrepo1/
main/subrepo1/subrepo2/
```

The default behavior of Mercurial is that when a `hg commit` is performed in "main", any outstanding changes in the subrepositories "subrepo1" and "subrepo2" will also be committed. Similarly, when "main" is pushed, any outgoing commits in "subrepo1" and "subrepo2" will also be pushed.

We find that people frequently inadvertently commit and push changes in their subrepositories (because they forgot they had made changes, and `hg status` by default does not show recursive changes). We also find that such global commits / pushes are almost always accidental in our team.

Mercurial 1.7 recently improved the situation with `hg status -S` and `hg outgoing -S`, which show changes in subrepositories; but still, this requires people to be paying attention.

**Is there a way in Mercurial to make `hg commit` and `hg push` abort if there are changes/commits in subrepostories that would otherwise be committed/pushed?**

Comment: Ry4an's solution sounds wise in many circumstances, but the script-based approach of the accepted answer was eventually what I used; so far, so good.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mercurial 2.0 automatically prevents you from committing subrepositories unless you manually specify the `--subrepos` (or, alternatively, `-S`) argument to `commit`.

For example, you try to perform a commit while there are pending changes in a subrepository, you get the following message:

```
# hg commit -m 'change main repo'
abort: uncommitted changes in subrepo hello
(use --subrepos for recursive commit)
```

You can successfully perform the commit, however, by adding `--subrepos` to the command:

```
# hg commit --subrepos -m 'commit subrepos'
committing subrepository hello
```

Some things to still be careful about: If you have changed the *revision* a subrepository is currently at, but not the *contents* of the subrepository, Mercurial will happily commit the version change without the `--subrepos` flag. Further, recursive pushes are still performed without warning.

Answer (score 11):

Since Mercurial 1.8 there is a configuration setting that [disables recursive commits](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository#Committing). In the parent repositories `.hg/hgrc` you can add:

```
[ui]
commitsubrepos = no
```

If a commit in the parent repository finds uncommitted changes in a subrepository the whole commit is aborted, instead of silently committing the subrepositories.

Comment: The default has changed for this option in Mercurial 2.0, so `hg commit` will not abort by default if there is a dirty subrepository.

Answer (score 4):

One notion is to use URLs to which you have read-only access in your `.hgsub` files.  Then when you do actually want to push in the subrepo you can just cd into it and do a `hg push THE_READ_WRITE_URL`.

Comment: Interesting idea. This has the benefit (and problem) of being a change that affects all users. I guess one way of doing this is to serve hg over http for the read-only, and allow standard ssh access for the read/write.

Comment: That's always been my preference anyway.  In a corporate setting I set up a read-only http:// repo so people can web browse or clone w/o bothering with access controls, and then use ssh:// for any selective access write-access requirements.

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution, using VonC's "pre-commit" idea.

Setup two scripts; the first `check_subrepo_commit.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# If the environment variable "SUBREPO" is set, allow changes.
[ "x$SUBREPO" != "x" ] && exit 0

# Otherwise, ensure that subrepositories have not changed.
LOCAL_CHANGES=`hg status -a -m`
GLOBAL_CHANGES=`hg status -S -a -m`
if [ "x${LOCAL_CHANGES}" != "x$GLOBAL_CHANGES" ]; then
    echo "Subrepository changes exist!"
    exit 1
fi
exit 0
```

The second, `check_subrepo_push.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# If the environment variable "SUBREPO" is set, allow changes.
[ "x$SUBREPO" != "x" ] && exit 0

# Otherwise, ensure that subrepositories have not changed.
LOCAL_CHANGES=`hg outgoing | grep '^changeset:'`
GLOBAL_CHANGES=`hg outgoing -S | grep '^changeset:'`
if [ "x${LOCAL_CHANGES}" != "x$GLOBAL_CHANGES" ]; then
    echo "Global changes exist!"
    exit 1
fi
exit 0
```

Add the following to your `.hgrc`:

```
[hooks]
pre-commit.subrepo = check_subrepo_commit.sh
pre-push.subrepo = check_subrepo_push.sh
```

By default, `hg push` and `hg commit` will abort if there are outstanding changes in subrepositories. Running a command like so:

```
SUBREPO=1 hg commit
```

will override the check, allowing you to perform the global commit/push if you really want to.

Answer (score 2):

May be a `pre-commit` hook ([not `precommit`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583957/custom-revision-properties-in-mercurial/4584474#4584474)) could do the `hg status -S` for you, and block the commit if it detects any changes?

Comment: Urgh. The distinction in Mercurial between `precommit` and `pre-commit` is terrible. I had tried the first without much luck, but the second looks more promising.

Comment: Yeah, the naming similarity is unfortunate.  There's a pre-X and post-X for every command and then there's an independent precommit hook that runs before the actual committing.