# Mercurial - Pushing Sub-Repo Heads

Tags: version-control, mercurial, mercurial-subrepos

How can I only push the needed HEADS of a subrepo from within the parent repo.

I've started using a bookmark style process for local feature branches in mercurial. It works great so far, just commit, bookmark and switch in and out of that head to work. I can push and pull just fine by specifying `hg push -r master-bookmark` to only push my main head and not any feature branches.

The problem comes when I use multiple heads with bookmarks in a subrepo. Because it means I cannot just use `hg push -r master-bookmark` because it then tries to push **all** the heads of the subrepo. I don't want these heads going public until I'm ready but I need to get some other changes out within the parent, so I'm not forcing them.

I've tried dropping into the sub-repo and pushing what I need, but the parent will still try and push everything regardless of whether it's in the ancestry of the `.hgsubstate'.

Any one got any ideas on what kind of workflow is best for this? I'd rather not have to disable the sub-repo, push, then re-enable, that will get very messy.

Comment: Not exactly the same question, but the answers might help you too (especially Ry4an's one): [Mercurial Subrepositories: Prevent accidental recursive commits and pushes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4856883/151299)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take advantage of the `phases` feature that makes this sort of workflow quite easy.

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Phases

When you make a branch/bookmark/commit phase `secret` it's not pushed unless you explicitly do so.  It's a great way to flag work that's not yet ready to share.

Comment: Aha! I only first read about phases today, and they struck me as very useful, information wise. I never thought of using them within the workflow. I'll try this tomorrow and see how it works out. Thanks.