# Mercurial bookmark to label failed TeamCity builds

Tags: mercurial, continuous-integration, teamcity, tortoisehg

Setup is

- a "central" hg repo and devs pulling from it.
- TeamCity CI server is triggered by pushes to the central repo.
- 4 configs are built nightly and tag the repo.

We want to visualize the information

> "this changeset resulted in a Failed CI build in TeamCity"

*directly inside the DAG of TortoiseHG.*

This way, devs are able to determine which changeset is "a good starting point", without having to look it up on the TeamCity server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ISO Mercurial "attributes" - tags that apply to more than one changeset, applied after the changeset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164296/iso-mercurial-attributes-tags-that-apply-to-more-than-one-changeset-applied)

Answer (score 0):

We are looking into **Mercurial Bookmarks**: setting them in a last build step when the CI build succeeded.

Advantages:

- they stand out in TortoiseHG
- adding or removing them doesn't increase the history

Disadvantages:

- pulling them over is not guaranteed
- they can be modified at will
- they are meant to move

Tags are less of an option: we are already tagging 4 times during nightly builds,
so those new tags would add to the clutter.
Also, we have no idea if tagging (a growing `.hgtags` file) will scale well with the extra tags.

Comment: You forgot one BIG Disadvantage of bookmarks: they are movable pointers, you can't have more than one bookmark with the same name on different csets, but in your use-case it must be possible (more than 1 changeset pushed. TeamCity test all changesets and more than 1 changeset failed)