# git pre-commit hook: changed files are not in the current commit

Tags: git, pre-commit-hook

I have a git pre-commit hook which changes some files if they are corrupt. After the hook is done the changed files are not listed in the current commit. How can I stage the changes from the hook into the current commit?

My hook looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
versionUpdater -editVersion
```

Which opens a windows forms where I can edit some versions from some files. After I finished editing I want that these changes are in the current commit.

Those changes from the hook are now listed in the next commit.

Comment: please post your code here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options.
the following answer will explain in details what needs to be done and how.

[Can a Git hook automatically add files to the commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284292/can-a-git-hook-automatically-add-files-to-the-commit).

In the pre-commit:

> - Touch a file .processCommit or something. (be sure to add this to .gitignore)

```
#!/bin/sh 
echo 
touch .processCommit 
exit
```

In the post-commit:

> if .processCommit exists you know a commit has just taken place.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo
if [ -a .commit ]
    then
    rm .commit
    git add yourfile
    git commit --amend -C HEAD --no-verify
fi
exit
```