# Run script before commit and include the update in this commit?

Tags: git, githooks

I wrote a script that generates `Readme.md` file (for GitHub) by scanning the source code. Everytime before I make a new commit, I run this script manually to update `Readme.md`. It sure would be better if this job being done automatically.

Currently I'm using `pre-commit` git hook, which works only partly. The `Readme.md` file gets updated, however the update is not part of this commit. I have to include it in the next commit.

Is there a way to run this script and make the update part of this commit?

Answer (score 8):

According to [this SO thread (Can a Git hook automatically add files to the commit?)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12802592/1919388), `git add` won't work on pre-commit hook with recent version of git.

As a workaround, you can play with pre-commit and post-commit hooks to generate your `Readme.md` then commit it after your commit with post-commit hook then ammend the second commit with yours.

Not's my idea, follow the links for original explanations.

Answer by [@bitluck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1731520/bitluck) on the thread I linked :

> Touch a file .commit or something. (be sure to add this to .gitignore)
>
> ```
> #!/bin/sh 
> echo 
> touch .commit 
> exit
> ```
>
> if .commit exists you know a commit has just taken place but a
>   post-commit hasn't run yet. So, you can do your code generation here.
>   Additionally, test for .commit and if it exists:
>
> - add the files
> - commit --amend -C HEAD --no-verify (avoid looping)
> - delete .commit file
>
>   ```
>   #!/bin/sh
>   echo
>   if [ -a .commit ]
>   then
>     rm .commit
>     git add yourfile
>     git commit --amend -C HEAD --no-verify
>   fi
>   exit
>   ```