# Pushing file to git that is not directly in repo with some sort of link

Tags: git, github, version-control, backup, bitbucket

I am not entirely sure what this feature is called, so I am just going to describe it, and perhaps someone can tell me how to do this.

I have a git repo called `mySettings` where I store my settings for various editors like Sublime.

Currently I am manually copying files between my local system and that repo, and then pushing them to the repo.

What I would ideally want is some sort of link between my local files and the repo so that every time I run say `git add . --all && git commit -m 'updated local files' && git push` it automagically pulls in all my local files that I have linked to that repo.

An example:

Say on my local system I have `~/FancyEditor/User/superbSettings` and I have my fancy repo `~/mySettings/` then if I were to run the above `git add . --all && git commit -m 'updated local files' && git push` inside `~/mySettings` it then has some form of link to `~/FancyEditor/User/superbSettings` thus relieving me of having to copy it to that repo every time I want to back it up.

Comment: Have you tried their desktop app? Just add  local repository and push it every time there is a change to the folder content.

Comment: [Githib desktop app](https://desktop.github.com/)

Comment: @Astrid If I recall correctly, if you add a link in your git repo to a local file. It just adds the symlinks, not the actual file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the best way is to use the symlinks. But currently git doesn't support using symlink files as a normal file, see: [How does git handle symbolic links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954560/how-does-git-handle-symbolic-links).

So the best way to do this is using the git hooks. just create a hook to execute the commands to copy the contents of the required files to the repository folder replacing the existing files. See the git hooks manual: https://git-scm.com/book/uz/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Example command:

```
cp -rf ~/FancyEditor/User/superbSettings ~/mySettings
```

See this too: [Run script before commit and include the update in this commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30376741/run-script-before-commit-and-include-the-update-in-this-commit)