# Git: Update git status part of commit message after pre-commit hook

Tags: git, commit, githooks, pre-commit-hook

I am running a pre-commit hook which potentially adds new files to the commit. However, although this technically works as expected, the `git status` part of the commit message does not reflect this change.

For example, I am adding file `x` in a commit, so my `git status` beforehand gives the following:

```
repo>git status
On branch development
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/development'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   x
```

Now, suppose my git hook determines file `y` also needs to be commited. Although afterwards I can see `y` was indeed staged for the commit, my empty commit message (after the pre-commit hook has executed) gives the following:

```
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
# On branch development
# Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/development'.
#
# Changes to be committed:
#       new file:   x
#
```

even though I am expecting

```
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
# On branch development
# Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/development'.
#
# Changes to be committed:
#       new file:   x
#       new file:   y
#
```

Indeed, after aborting the commit I get the following `git status`:

```
repo>git status
On branch development
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/development'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   x
        new file:   y
```

In other words, how do I 'refresh' the automatically generated part of my commit message in the pre-commit hook?

EDIT:
My pre-commit hook currently looks as follows.

```
#!/bin/sh
gulp --production

vendor/bin/phpunit

rc=$?
if [[ $rc != 0 ]] ; then
    echo "phpunit failed - commit denied"
    exit $rc
fi

git add public
```

`gulp` does things like compile SCSS and potentially move things to my public/ directory. If this happens I want to add those files to the commit, hence the `git add public` directive at the end.
So even though these files *do* get added to the commit, the `git status` part of the commit message does not reflect this.

Comment: Can you post the code of the pre-commit-hook?

Comment: I had found this question already, but is not applicable to my problem exactly, since I am writing my commit message before any post-commit hook is executed

Comment: Ah, I see. I was hoping someone might have had (or has) a workaround, but I guess I'll have to make do otherwise

Answer (score 0):

It seems the git status part in git commit-msg is created before the pre-commit-hook is run. So although it won't be shown in COMMIT-MSG, it will be committed nonetheless. It seems to be a small bug with git.

[Can a Git hook automatically add files to the commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284292/can-a-git-hook-automatically-add-files-to-the-commit)