# Using git add inside a pre-commit hook

Tags: git, eslint, post-commit, pre-commit

***TL;DR: Using `eslint --fix` && `git add` in a pre-commit hook works but it leaves staged and not staged files! Using a post-commit hook to `git reset <staged-files>` seems to work but is there a solution for this?***

To give some background, I started using `lint-staged` and `husky` to automatically fix JavaScript lint errors on `git commit`. This works extremely well if you staged your changes first and then commit, for example:

```
git add index.js
git commit -m "Some Message"
```

IntelliJ IDEA seems to commit files directly *(e.g. `git commit -m "Some Message" index.js`)* which still works, the automatically fixed files are committed. **Unfortunately, it also leaves a staged file (auto-fixed) and a not staged file (original lint errors) and this is the problem I am wanting to resolve.**

Not knowing where to begin I opened **[issue 151](https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged/issues/151)** with `lint-staged` but after some investigation, the problem seems to be related to Git and not `lint-staged`.

I only have basic Git skills, so to minimize distractions, I created a project without `lint-staged` or `husky` and manually added a pre-commit hook. I then ran the same tests *(e.g. `git commit -m "Some Message" index.js`)* and unsurprisingly the same issue appeared. In an attempt to resolve the problem I also added a post-commit hook that runs `git reset <staged-files>` which appears to work well, but I'm unsure if it's the correct solution.

If you have experience with this or you're a Git Guru, take a look at the **[demo repo](https://github.com/samit4me/precommit-eslint-fix-demo)** and let us know if there is a better way. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have the exact same issue. Did you find anything Samuel?

Comment: No, doesn't seem possible :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a Git hook automatically add files to the commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284292/can-a-git-hook-automatically-add-files-to-the-commit)

Answer (score 1):

See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/oauth?state=%2Fissue%2FIDEA-135454

Workaround: Add `git update-index -g` as postcommit hook.