# Git add in pre-commit hook not staging file for commit

Tags: git, pre-commit-hook, git-husky

I have written a pre-commit hook that compiles my project and adds the generated file to the commit.

This is a JavaScript project and I am using husky, but I have experimented with editing the .git/hooks/pre-commit as well and the file is not getting added to the commit. If I cancel the commit, I can see the file has been added, but for some reason this is not applying to the current commit.

My pre-commit hook looks something like:

```
const shell = require('shelljs');

shell.exec('yarn bundle');
shell.exec('git add dist');
shell.exit(0);
```

`shelljs` is just a library to execute cross-OS unix commands in node

I edited the `.git/hooks/pre-commit` to run `git add dist` and the file is still not added to the commit

Comment: Is the hook actually executed? It needs the executable bit set, and might be ignored if it is not there. Also check without the shelljs, calling `git add dist` directly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a Git hook automatically add files to the commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284292/can-a-git-hook-automatically-add-files-to-the-commit)

Comment: The hook is definitely executed yeah, and I did try just running `git add dist` but it still didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think a `git add` can work in a **[pre-commit hook](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_committing_workflow_hooks)**, made to inspect what is about to be committed, not to modify it.

You can follow an approach similar to "[Can a Git hook automatically add files to the commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12802592/6309)" instead, which creates a separate additional commit.

Comment: Adding files via pre-commit hooks actually works. consider the simplest hook `echo text > test.file && git add test.file` - worked for me.

Comment: What about pre-push? You can commit always, but when trying to push, you can actually generate other files, add them, commit them programmatically, and issue a exit(0) so the push will happen. But yes, "seems wrong" as @VonC said.

Comment: Thanks @VonC using that other question's solution did help me, but I would have liked to be able to add an extra file in the pre-commit hook...