# Git pre-commit hook isn't executed

Tags: node.js, git, nuxt.js, pre-commit-hook, playwright

I want to execute a node.js script in a pre-commit hook.

- Expected result: node.js script is executed
- Actual result: Nothing happens, no error, no logs, nothing

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Run pre-commit hook"
node [project]/scripts/generate-social-media-preview/index.js
git add .
echo "Finished pre-commit hook"
exit 0
```

Of course, I also tried to run the node.js directly in the `pre-commit`, by changing the first line to: `#!/usr/bin/env node`. Same result.

The script executes playwright, manipulates an HTML template, takes a screenshot, and saves it. All of this lives in a nuxt.js project, so the script and the rest of the project are using one shared node-modules folder and package.json.

If I just run `[project]/scripts/generate-social-media-preview/index.js` it does exactly what it should do. I made the file executable.

I normally commit via Webstorm, but I also did it with the terminal and I never saw an output or that the images got generated accordingly.

Also, husky and pre-commit were on my list, but it behaved as with the native pre-commit hook.

I would be happy to solve this "within the code" to not have a plugin or local script which triggers this, also running this during `npm run generate` isn't working as my website is hosted at Netlify and of course, there isn't chromium available for playwright.

The whole code can be seen here (with all my test commits...): https://github.com/LukaHarambasic/harambasic.de/pull/46

Comment: Is your hook file executable?

Comment: You never did describe what was the result when it's executed as a hook.

Comment: @knittl yes it is.

Comment: @jingx I added the expected and actual result.

Answer (score 0):

So, there were two problems:

1. WebStorm doesn't handle pre-commit hooks very well and for me, somehow isn't working with husky. From now on, I'll do commands via the command line. If you want to know more, read [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-264817) and [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-244581) issue. -> let me know if you find a solution
2. Committing files in a pre-commit hook isn't very reliable - check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284292/can-a-git-hook-automatically-add-files-to-the-commit) question to see the solution with a pre-commit and post-commit hook.