# pre-commit hook executes proper but doesn't commit the changes after

Tags: git, pre-commit

I am using `php-cs-fixer` and decided to try to put the command in `pre-commit` hook.
#!/bin/sh

```
echo "php-cs-fixer pre commit hook start"

SRC="src/Controller/Api/FlowsController.php"

exec tools/php-cs-fixer/vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer fix $SRC

echo "php-cs-fixer pre commit hook finish"
```

So the `php-cs-fixer` command works fine, but the changes are not commited after it. I also don't see the final `echo` statement when the hook is done. What I see on committing is:

```
toma.tomov@MBP-TOMA myproject % git commit -m "test"
php-cs-fixer pre commit hook start
Loaded config default from "/Users/toma.tomov/Desktop/projects/myproject/.php-cs-fixer.dist.php".
Using cache file ".php-cs-fixer.cache".
Paths from configuration file have been overridden by paths provided as command arguments.
   1) src/Controller/Api/FlowsController.php

Fixed all files in 2.028 seconds, 26.000 MB memory used
[PHP-CS-FIXER 9550f90a22] test
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+)
```

Answer (score 3):

Pre-commit hooks in general *should not try* to change what will be committed.  Depending on how you invoke Git, they maybe *unable* to change what will be committed.  A pre-commit hook should therefore only *verify that what you plan to commit is correct* (according to whatever correctness rules you'd like to enforce).

There are some exceptions to the above rules, but you must know a great deal about Git's internal operation before you break these rules.  If you'd like to, e.g., reformat or otherwise fix up files before committing, you should do this as a separate step.

Hint: don't run `git commit` at all.  Run *your own program*, which runs the file-fixing step, then runs `git add`, then runs `git commit`.  You can retain the *checking* hooks (which verify that what's to be committed looks right, then allows or denies the commit) and since the file-fixing step has run *before* the `git add` step, everything should always pass.

Comment: yeah, think pre-commit hooks as "code-format-validator" not "code-formatter".

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have a pre-commit hook that does this:

1. Creates or modifies a `file`
2. runs `git add file`

It will work *IF AND ONLY IF*, there was already something to be commited. It does not have to be the same file tho. If there was nothing to be commited, the git add `git add file` will work, but will not be commited.

**Example that works:**

1. You changed a file, and added it (for example, the `gitignore`)

```
$> git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
        new file:   .gitignore
```

2. Run commit. First, the `pre-commit` hook will run and create `file`. Then it will commit.

```
--- Dataset Pre-Commit Hook ---
--- Done ---
[master (root-commit) 2ba2f7c] First commit
 3 files changed, 34 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 .gitignore
 create mode 100644 file
```

3. You can see the message says `file` was commited. And `git status` now outputs:

```
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

**Example that DOES NOT work**

1. You have nothing to add. You can of course run `git add` but it will do nothing. `git status` gives:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

2. Run commit. The hook will create `file`. But the commit message says he did nothing.

```
--- Dataset Pre-Commit Hook ---
--- Done ---
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

3. Verify the status `git status`

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        modified:   file
```

3. You can see that file was indeed modified, and that it was added, but yet not commited. You need to run `git commit` again for it to work.

I tried adding that as a `post-commit` hook but got no luck. If someone knows a fix for this case, I would love to know.